# inner query of subqery returning multiple rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am not that experience in sql so please forgive if its not a good question to ask,but i researched around almost for 3-4 days but no able to solve.
My problem is i have a table which have multiple image names in it,so what i have to do is whoever is the follower of a particular user i have to get the imaged from this table,so one user there can be multiple followers,so i have to fetch the images posted by all the followers.
Here is the subquery code snippet i am using.

```
SELECT id,
       outfit_image,
       img_title,
       description
FROM outfitpic_list r2 
WHERE Email=ANY(SELECT being_followed 
                FROM follower_table 
                WHERE follower='test@gmail.com')
```

So the inner query here returns multiple values,for each value(being_followed) i have to fetch all the images and display it,but with this query each time i get only one image.I tried IN also but didnot work out.

Table structure:-
Outfitpic_list table

```
   id|outfit_image|datetime|Email|image_title|description
```

Follower_table

```
   bring_followed|follower
```

Please help,I am stuck..!!
Thank you..!!

Comment: Please show the relevant table structures. And also use code tags to display SQL queries more clearly.

Comment: @kaykay:-Thanks for respose.
THe table structure has only these columns,do you want something else?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be the = sign between "E-mail" and "Any". Try this statement:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  outfit_image,
  img_title,
  description 
FROM outfitpic_list r2 
WHERE Email IN
(
  SELECT being_followed 
  FROM follower_table 
  WHERE follower='test@gmail.com'
)
```

It's the same statement, without the = sign, and the ANY keyword replaced with IN. (I cleaned it up a little to make it more readable)

Comment: @podiluska I didn't realize that, thanks! In that case, as KayKay mentioned, we would probably need to see the table structures to provide more info :)

Comment: Yes - I can't see a flaw in the query, so either i've lost my touch, or its somewhere else

Comment: Hey,
Thanks all.But no luck this time,this query also doesnot work.

Comment: Please have a look again i have edited the question with table structure.